# ObjectDisposedException when I try to use an Image source

Tags: c#, wpf, image, exception, stream

I need to add an `Image` to my Panel, so I use the following code:

```
var image = new Image();
var source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
source.StreamSource = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
source.EndInit();

// I close the StreamSource so I can load again the same file
source.StreamSource.Close();
image.Source = source;
```

The problem is that when I try to use my image source I get an `ObjectDisposedException`:

```
var source = ((BitmapImage)image.Source).StreamSource;

// When I use source I get the exception
using (var stream = new MemoryStream((int)(source.Length)))
{
    source.Position = 0;
    source.CopyTo(stream);
    // ...
}
```

It happens because I closed the source, but if I don't close it I can't be able to load again the same file.

How can I solve this problem (i.e. close the source to be able to load the same file more than once, and to be able to use the source without get the exception)?

Comment: Why not to pass the Uri source directly and let the component handle it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970269(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SebastianPiu I can't use the UriSource because when I retrieve the StreamSource it is null.

Comment: You should not dispose the stream of the image. Keep it open as long as your are displaying the image

Comment: @Nick UriSource is an _alternative_ to StreamSource.  If you use one, you should not touch the other.  I would recommend using UriSource if possible, in which case you will not need to dispose of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution should work for you:

```
var image = new Image();
var source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

// Create a new stream without disposing it!
source.StreamSource = new MemoryStream();

using (var filestream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
   // Copy the file stream and set the position to 0
   // or you will get a FileFormatException
   filestream.CopyTo(source.StreamSource);
   source.StreamSource.Position = 0;
}

source.EndInit();
image.Source = source;
```